# QAF | How to reset retry.count for executing testcase

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, qaf

application properties: retry.count = 5

One of the element locators is getting visible only during the 3rd or 4th retry, but if another element is also having the same issue within the given testcase, it never goes for 5 retries. Testcase fails after remaining retry left.

I have also noticed that the test case starts from the start after 5th retry and fails.

I have also referred the doc:
https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html

Answer (score 1):

`retry.count` [property used by framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html) to determine number of retry of test case on failure not for element failure retry. For element failure retry you can impement [web-element listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#webelement-listener). Regarding element visibility you can try increasing wait time out using `selenium.wait.timeout` [property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html)